# ASP .NET web api: return raw data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing REST ASP .NET Web Api service for multiple clients - mobile devices, plugins and so on.
Mostly, my web api methods return specific objects (or lists of objects), so the client will easily consume web service by using some libraries/packages which work with JSON objects.
However, is it good practice to return just raw data, which is not wrapped into object?

For example, method, that returns just int.

```
public int GetProductsCount()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Does this go againgst RESTful service concept? Will it be easy to consume such API for different clients   (using different programming languages)?

Thanks

Comment: stackoverfolw is not for code review. Ask concrete question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no compelling rule against this practice, no.  If `1` is the only thing the client needs to know, then there's no need to return anything more than `1`.  You certainly *can* wrap this value in a custom object to provide *more* information (response codes, metadata, etc.), but if there *isn't* more information then there's no need to do that.